# Cypress 10 - variables between cypress tests

Tags: cypress

I am trying to get a value from response body and then using it in another it-s in Cypress 10. I have created custom cy.task for get and set global variable, but it's not a good solution when I need for example 10 values from previous test:

```js
await cy.task("getValue", {key: "one"}).then((one){
    await cy.task("getValue", {key: "two"}).then((two){
        await cy.task("getValue", {key: "three"}).then((three){
            await cy.task("getValue", {key: "four"}).then((four){
                ...
                if(one === null && two === null && three == null && four == null){
                    do smth
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Another solution is get value from cy.task and save it into local variable:

```js
let one_helper;
let two_helper;
let ...
cy.task("getValue", {key: "one"}).then((one){
    one_helper = one;
}
cy.task("getValue", {key: "two"}).then((two){
    two_helper = two;
}
...
if(one_helper == null && two_helper == null){
    do smth
}
```

But it's not a good solution for me because I have a lots of values from previous response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Cypress.env()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/env#Syntax) to save any value globally.

```js
Cypress.env('somekey', 'somevalue') //saves the value
Cypress.env('somekey') //gets 'somevalue'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass an array of keys to one task call.

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')

const store = {}

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on('task', {
        getValue(keys) {
          if (typeof keys === 'string') {  // only a single key? 
            keys = [keys]                  // arrayify it
          }
          return keys.map(key => store[key])
        },
      })
    }
  }
})
```